# Why is only one property being printed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I'm working on a project with Google Apps Scripts that use the scriptProperties service to save text a user inputs and print what was input last when the program is opened later. The problem I'm running into is it's only printing the most recently saved value and the others are not printing out as expected. ONLY the most recently saved property.

Here's what I'm working with.

This is the HTML document.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      var inputs = {};

      <? var data = sendData(); ?> 

     function captureInputs() {
       google.script.run.storeData(inputs);
     }

     function title() {
       var inputTitle = document.getElementById("metaTitle").value;
       inputs.title = inputTitle;
      }

     function url() {
       var inputUrl = document.getElementById("url").value;
       inputs.url = inputUrl;
       }

     function desc() {
       var inputDesc = document.getElementById("metaDescription").value;
       inputs.desc = inputDesc;
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <? if (data.title !== "undefined") { ?>
        <input value="<?= data.title ?>" type="text" oninput="title();captureInputs();>
      <? } else { ?>
        <input value="" type="text" oninput="title();captureInputs();>
    <? } ?>

    <? if (data.url !== "undefined") { ?>
        <input value="<?= data.url ?>" type="text" oninput="url();captureInputs();>
      <? } else { ?>
        <input value="" type="text" oninput="url();captureInputs();>
    <? } ?>

    <? if (data.desc !== "undefined") { ?>
      <input value="<?= data.desc ?>" type="text" oninput="desc();captureInputs();>
    <? } else { ?>
      <input value="" type="text" oninput="desc();captureInputs();>
    <? } ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is what i have in the JS file.

```
function sendData() {
  var data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  return data;
  }

function storeData(inputs) {
 var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
 scriptProperties.setProperty('title', inputs.title);
 scriptProperties.setProperty('url', inputs.url);
 scriptProperties.setProperty('desc', inputs.desc);
 }
```

So for example, if I saved something to data.title, then data.desc would show up as undefined (it also *sometimes* shows up as blank) even though I have a property saved there. If I rewrite data.desc, then data.title would show up as empty.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

PS. This is obviously not the full program but I shortened it to where I'm running into issues.

Comment: How exactly are you saving `data.title`?

Comment: Your script is working for me.  I just loaded the data into the Script Properties via File/Project Properties

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't include everything I have in the example above but I have an oninput attribute on the input elements that updates an object and then sends it to the serverside which adds them to the properties

Comment: Show your setter call

Comment: Show that code. Issue is in there

Comment: @TheMaster edited to include more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

Overwriting properties with `undefined`. For example, when `oninput="desc();captureInputs();"` is triggered, `inputs` is a object with only `desc` key.

```
inputs={desc:"metaDescription"}
```

It doesn't contain `url` or `title` key. So, it'll be undefined and will save as undefined. For example,

```
scriptProperties.setProperty('title', inputs.title);
```

will store `title` as `undefined`, when `desc();captureInputs()` is called.

#### Solution:

Use `setProperties()` instead to avoid overwriting stored property values:

```
function storeData(inputs) {
 var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
/* scriptProperties.setProperty('title', inputs.title);
 scriptProperties.setProperty('url', inputs.url);
 scriptProperties.setProperty('desc', inputs.desc);*/
 scriptProperties.setProperties(inputs, false);
 }
```

#### References:

- [setProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties.html#setProperties(Object,Boolean))

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to your html so I could change and save the data and then restart the dialog to see that it gets my changes and it does.

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
      <? var data = sendData(); ?> 
      function saveData() {
       var obj={title:$('#title').val(),desc:$('#desc').val(),url:$('#url').val()};
       $('#title').val('');//set text to blank on the way to server
       $('#desc').val('');
       $('#url').val('');
       google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){
         $('#title').val(obj.title);//set text to new values 
         $('#desc').val(obj.desc);
         $('#url').val(obj.url);
       })
       .saveData(obj);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <? if (data.title !== "undefined") { ?>
        <input value="<?= data.title ?>" type="text" id="title" />
      <? } else { ?>
        <input value="" type="text">
    <? } ?>

    <? if (data.url !== "undefined") { ?>
        <input value="<?= data.url ?>" type="text" id="url" />
      <? } else { ?>
        <input value="" type="text">
    <? } ?>

    <? if (data.desc !== "undefined") { ?>
      <input value="<?= data.desc ?>" type="text" id="desc"/>
    <? } else { ?>
      <input value="" type="text">
    <? } ?>
    <input type="button" value="Save" onClick="saveData();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function sendData() {
  var data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  return data;
}

function runDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('aq7').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Testing');
}
//Save all of the values
function saveData(obj) {
  for(key in obj) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key,obj[key]);
  }
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
}
```